# How can I publish changes related to DL from staging to the live?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I've enabled **local staging** on the global site. I'm creating files and directories programmatically in DL under the global site. I've to publish changes related to particular DL from staging to live. **How can I publish changes related to DL from staging to the live?**

Environment detail: Liferay 7.1.0 GA1 - Community Edition

Comment: 1. [Upgrade](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1)!, 2. this is a question about _using_ Liferay, _not_ about custom _development_, thus off-topic on stackoverflow. Please read [help/on-topic] - the question would be on-topic on the Liferay forums.

Comment: I've to publish files and directories from staging to live programmatically.